# Accessing App Settings from Azure Portal in React App

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a React application deployed in Azure.

I need to make something easily configurable in the UI and for that I need to change the configurable variable without touching the code.

I also have a .net core api deployed in Azure that the React App uses. In .net Core, we use the launchSettings.json file to access configurable variables that we store in Azure Portal.

[image]

Is there a similar solution for React, where we can change the variable in Azure Portal App Settings and use that to make some UI part configurable?

We already have config files in React for different environments and use that in the code, but to change something in them, I need to make changes to the code and redeploy the application again. I want to know if there is way to do it without touching the code and redeploying it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find any solution ? I am also looking for a similar  implementation

Answer (score 0):

React runs in your browser unlike the .NET Core App. So, you could either fetch config from a JSON file hosted alongside your application or from a database via a REST endpoint.

It could even just be a simple JSON file hosted on blob storage for example.

**PS:** Note that JS code runs in the browser and any checks can be overridden by an experienced developer with effort. All data should be protected by your backend behind authentication/authorization.